# Connecting blogger blog with subdomain.mysite.com, is it good for www.mysite.com SEO/pagerank?

Tags: seo, subdomain, blogger

I client of mine has a static website www.mysite.com and a blogger blog with the same subject mysiteblog.blogspot.com and wants to move the blog inside mysite.com to give her site a SEO boost. Will connecting blogspot with the subdomain blog.mysite.com affect page rank and search results for the main domain? How do the search engines crawl a domain witch is both static html (main site) and blogger structure (subdomain)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will most definitely improve rankings on the main site (www.mysite.com). Google is known to be fond of regularly updated content, so a blog is a good move for the site. The way Google crawls the site is no different for a blog vs static HTML pages. I would just ensure that you have a Sitemap (and have it submitted to Google webmaster tools) to give it a bit of a helping hand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How about google treating subdomains as different sites (subdomain vs folder for blog)? Regarding sitemap, how can I submit a sitemap for both the static site and the blogger? I found this relative link: [link](http://www.labnol.org/internet/submit-blogger-sitemap-to-google/10149/)

Comment: Historically, subdomains were regarded as a good thing. However, i think the general consensus nowadays is that it's better to keep all content on the root of the domain. That said, i don't think it will adversely affect the ranking of the site if the blog is on a subdomain. Just make sure it is ONLY on the subdomain and you DO NOT have duplicate content indexed - Google hates it).